# "Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard"" error in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop I'm creating a 'MonoTouch Single View Application - Universal (Storyboard)', when I compile the solution I get the following error:

> Compiling interface definitions /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors
>   --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text
>   "/Users/dev/Projects/JScanner/JScanner/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard"
>   --compile
>   "/Users/dev/Projects/JScanner/JScanner/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/JScanner.app/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboardc"
>   --sdk
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk"
>   /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
>   /Users/dev/Projects/JScanner/JScanner/MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard:
>   error: Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of
>   "MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard". ibtool exited with code 1 Build
>   complete -- 1 error, 0 warnings

This is just the basic solution, so I haven't added any new source files or views into it yet.

Comment: Storyboards are part of a yet to be released SDK version..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error will be fixed in the next version of MonoDevelop. For now, I would suggest you use xib-based projects.

Comment: ah cheers, was a bit worried it was something to do with my code :P